# Clustering Highly Skewed and Segmented Data

Tags: clustering, k-means, skewness, dbscan, model-based-clustering

So I am trying to cluster a dataset that looks like the following:

[image: My Data]

I have tried K-Means and GMM, which give me horrible results. I have tried DBSCAN, which was okay, but it is difficult to choose the parameters.

What techniques would you use? I am thinking about a Box-Cox transform, then using K-Means again, or trying a different distance measure (p<1) but I wanted to get some expert opinions as well.

So, what should I use?

Comment: Have you tried scaling the data?

Comment: @honeybadger Yes I have. It just gives me smaller values on the axes but the problem still remains.

Comment: hey.. are you trying to cluster only using dimension 1 and dimension 2? First of all, dimension doesn't look like a continuous variable.. is it something else?